# iTunes Connectへの提出ができない (ERROR ITMS-90207: "Invalid Bundle)

Tags: ios, ios8, xcode7

アプリをiTunes Connectへの提出ができなくなってしまいました。（Archiveするところまではできます。）

２週間前に前のバージョンを提出したときは問題なかったのですが。とくにビルド設定を変更した覚えはありません。

症状として、iTunes Connectへの提出プロセスのインジゲーターがほとんど終わりそうなときに、下記のメッセージが表示されます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

本家のStackoverflowで同じような症状に関する質問があり（https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31793854/error-itms-90207-invalid-bundle）
Mach-O TypeをDynamicに変更してみたのですが、この変更後はArchiveもできなくなってしまいましたので元に戻しました。

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33369777/xcode-app-submisson-error-itms-90207-invalid-bundle
でサジェストされている２つの解決策についても試してみたのですがダメでした。

今日丸一日この問題でスタックしてしまい、どうにも進めない状況です。
これを試してみては？というアドバイス等あれば、ぜひお願いします。

環境: Xcode 7.1 (Swift)、Deployment Target iOS8.2, Mac OS 10.11.1(El Capitan)

Comment: Xcodeを7.1.1に上げてみてはどうでしょうか？

Comment: 提案ありがとうございます。7.1.1にしてみたのですが、だめでした。いろいろ試行錯誤したら、bitcodeの設定を変えることでうまくいきました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build settingのenable bitcodeをNOにし、提出時にinclude bitcodeのチェックボックスをオフにしたらエラーが出なくなりました。

他に同じ問題で悩んでいる方がいれば、試してみてください。